Selecting elements of vectors in a list
I have a list with 3 (or more) vectors of characters ordered by total of elements
The first vector has 18 elements
The second vector has 623 elements
The third vector has 1706 elements
I would like to selected 256 elements randomly and not duplicated getting these 256 elements in ordered way. One element of vector which less elements, after the other element of the second vector which less elements and so on, until 256 elements to be selected. How can I do this?
My code until now is:
selected_files <- c()

for(i in files_train) {
  
  selected_files <- c(selected_files, sample(files_train, 1, replace = F))
  
  if(sum(sapply(selected_files, length)) == 256) {
    
    break
    
  }
}

files_train is my list with, in this case 3 vectors, with different lengths, already ordered.
How can I solve this?
Thanks for any help.

See if this approach works for you sample(unlist(list(v1, v2, v3)), 256)

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What type of "ordered way" are you referring to specifically? It is possible that no values are selected from one of the sublists?

It seems like your current code is already doing what you want. Could you please say more about why, exactly, the current code isn't sufficient? Do you just need it ordered (e.g., vector1, vector2, vector3, vector1, vector2, vector3, etc.)?

I need that get elements of each vector, 1 element per vector per loop and repeat this process untill get 256 elements. The desired output, in this specific case would be v1=18 elements, V2=119 and v3=119 elements.

unlist(Map(sample, list(v1, v2, v3), c(18, 119, 119)))

I like of this approach @Onyambu, however, this is a example, sometimes this number of vectors and quantities of elements in each could vary. I pretend generalize it, for that my loop could determine this quantity automatically.

How do you determine the sample from each vector?

In this way: getting 1 element per vector per loop and repeat this process until the list contains 256 elements.
example: If I have 256 vectors, so there will be 256 vectors with 1 element each. As I have 3 vectors being one with 18 elements, so the vec1 will get 18 elements and the others more than 18, but the total of list has to be 256.

@WilsonSouza then thats a simple math problem. eg 256 //3 = 85. Then you can tell that one of the vectors is less than 85, so you have then you take them off 256. ie 256 - 18 = 238, now you divide by 2, you get 119. If you had another vector less than that, you take it off..continue the process to the end.

Just do some constrained optimization to obtain the lengths then do sampling with the code I gave

Thanks for all help
I solve my question with this code below:
selected_files <- list()

while(sum(unlist(lapply(selected_files, length))) < 256) {
  for(i in names(files_train)[order(sapply(files_train, length), decreasing = F)]) {
    
    files <- setdiff(files_train[[i]], selected_files[[i]])
    
    if(length(files) >= 1) {
      selected_files[[i]] <- c(selected_files[[i]], sample(files, 1))
    }
    
    if(sum(sapply(selected_files, length)) >= 256) {
      cat(sum(sapply(selected_files, length)))
      break
    }
  }
}

